# Azure function works when manually run but not from trigger. HttpClient results empty

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure Function that simply calls a web service using HttpClient, retrieves some JSON and logs the string. It works exactly as expected when manually run from the online editor "Run" button but the result string is empty when run via a timer trigger (running various times...1 min...10 min....doesn't matter). The function completes "successfully" either way.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<BASEURL>");

    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new 
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

     HttpResponseMessage response = 
     client.GetAsync("/api/opportunities").Result;

    string stringData =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    log.Info(stringData);

    List<Opportunity> oppList = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Opportunity>>(stringData);
```

I'm at a loss of what to check next. Thoughts?

Comment: can you check the response status code before reading the contents from it and log error details if it is not 200

 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        { 
            log.Info(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // problems handling here
            log.Info(
                "Error occurred, the status code is: {0}", 
                response.StatusCode
            );
        }

Comment: Can you post the http function code as well? What language are you using?

Comment: @NareshPodishetty I always get a 200 status code from the web service.

Comment: @MattMason-MSFT The web service is a C# asp.net core application that queries data from a DB and relays it. I can use Postman or other means to check the web service and it is always populated.

Comment: Perhaps try application insights? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-functions-now-integrated-with-application-insights/

You should be able to enable http request tracing to get more info about request contents.

Comment: Also, what is the signature of your timer function?

Comment: Thanks for the continued help @MattMason-MSFT . I'll look into App Insights but I'm afraid I don't understand what the "signature" of the timer function is. 

Interesting to note that I recreated the logic of the function in Javascript instead of C# and have the same results. Works when manually run but the http ("request") call is empty when initiated by the timer. 

I also created a new "function application" using an app service plan vs consumption....same result. 

So bizarre.

Comment: Tested with a generic web service (http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all) and the function works correctly from a timer trigger so there's something odd about my web service or the Azure-to-Azure communication.